# Select max value in dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

My drop down list  selected value is :

```
{1,2,3,4}
```

when new item add i need select max selected value in drop down list.how can select max drop down list .selected value with LINQ ?

```
ddlFolder.DataBind();
ddlFolder.SelectedValue ='how can select max in drop down list values with linq';
```

how can do with linq to select  max in drop down list values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `DataBind` i assume it's an `ASP.NET` `DropDownList`:

```
int maxValue = ddlFolder.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Max(li => int.Parse(li.Value));
ddlFolder.SelectedValue = maxValue.ToString();
```

Note that the `Cast<ListItem>()` is needed here because a [`ListItemCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) returned from `DropDownList.Items` is older than generics in .NET. Therefore it only implements `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<ListItem>`. Otherwise you could omit the cast.

Comment: see:https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-US/training-courses/demystifying-linq-12301

Comment: @shahroz: best tutorial is learning by doing and reading/answering questions on SO.

Comment: @shahroz: it's stackoverflow ;)